# VB.net returns chr(255) as chr(63)

Tags: vb.net, chr

I am writing a program in visual basic and have run into an odd problem.  I am sending strings via  serial port to a telescope mount.  When I send the `check` string, the scope can return either chr(0) or chr(255).  This works fine in python and c++ returning chr(255).  However when I run the script in visual basic it returns chr(0) or chr(63).

below are two identical functions one in python and one in visual basic.

Can anyone give me an idea why visual basic returns 63 instead of 255?

**function in python (returns correct values 0 and 255):**

```
global d, check
d=chr(80)+chr(4)+chr(16)+chr(2)+chr(1)+chr(112)+chr(252)+chr(0)
check=chr(80) + chr(1) + chr(16) + chr(19) + chr(0) + chr(0) + chr(0)+chr(1)


def test():
    ser.write(d)
    time.sleep(.1)
    print ser.readline()
    ser.write(check)
    time.sleep(.1)
    out=ser.readline()[0]
    print "out=",ord(out)
    while out == chr(0):
            print "out = ", ord(out)
            ser.write(check)
        time.sleep(.1)
            out=ser.readline()[0]
        print "out=",ord(out)
    print "out is now", ord(out)
    ser.readline()
```

**script in visual basic (returns incorrect values 0 and 63)**

```
Public Sub test()
    Dim out As Char
    Dim d As String = Chr(80) + Chr(4) + Chr(16) + Chr(2) + Chr(1) + Chr(112) + Chr(252) + Chr(0)
    Dim check As String = Chr(80) + Chr(1) + Chr(16) + Chr(19) + Chr(0) + Chr(0) + Chr(0) + Chr(1)
    port.Write(d)
    Threading.Thread.Sleep(100)
    Console.Write(port.ReadTo("#"))
    port.Write(check)
    Threading.Thread.Sleep(100)
    out = port.ReadTo("#")
    Console.Write(vbNewLine & "out=" & out)
    While out = Chr(0)
        Console.Write("out = " & Convert.ToInt16(out))
        port.Write(check)
        Threading.Thread.Sleep(0.1)
        out = port.ReadTo("#")
        Console.Write("out=" & Convert.ToInt16(out))
    End While
    Console.Write("out is now" & Convert.ToInt16(out))
    port.ReadLine()


End Sub
```

Comment: according to msdn char type holds unsigned 16-bit (2-byte) code points

Answer (score 9, accepted):

The .NET `SerialPort` class has [an `Encoding` associated with it](https://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/system.io.ports.serialport.encoding.aspx) that is used for conversion between text and bytes sent on the port. The documentation says that it's used for "pre- and post-transmission conversion of text".  It's not exactly clear that the `Encoding` is used to convert bytes received into text for the `string` returned fromt `ReadTo()` (but that might be what is meant by "post-transmission").

In any case, I'm pretty sure that that is what's happening to your `255` character.  The `ReadTo()` method uses the `Encoding` to convert the data received to text to put in the `string`.  The default `Encoding` is `ASCIIEncoding`, which only deals with characters in the range `0x00` - `0x7f`.  Bytes outside of that range will be encoded into `'?'` characters, which happens to have an ASCII value of `63`.

Use the `ReadByte()` method instead to read the data from the port without any text encoding getting involved.

**Update**: I have found a blog posting from someone on the BCL team that confirms this and also points out an encoding object that will pass 8-bit data unmodified. Ryan Byington wrote in an article called ["SerialPort Encoding" on the Base Class Library (BCL) Blog](http://blogs.msdn.com/b/bclteam/archive/2006/05/26/608377.aspx) on 26 May 2006:

> The `SerialPort` class uses the encoding specified by the
>   `SerialPort.Encoding` property to convert strings and character arrays
>   to bytes to send across the serial port. This encoding also gets used
>   when reading from the serial port to convert bytes received by the
>   serial port to strings and character arrays.
>
> By default the `SerialPort` class uses ASCII encoding which converts all
>   characters with the value of 0-127 to a single byte with the same
>   value. So "Hello" gets converted to the byte array {72, 101, 108, 108,
>   111}. However every other character gets converted to a byte with the
>   value of 63 or the `'?'` character. This applies for reading as well so
>   if the serial port received the byte array {72, 101, 108, 108, 111} it
>   will convert this to "Hello" and any byte with a value greater then
>   127 will get converted to the `'?'` character.
>
> The ASCII encoding works perfectly fine for most serial devices but
>   there are still quite a few device that either send bytes with values
>   beyond 127 or you need to send bytes with values greater then 127. You
>   have two options; one would be to use the API’s that deal with `byte[]`
>   and bypass the `Encoding`, or to use the correct Encoding. However
>   finding the correct encoding is a bit tricky as most encodings that
>   deal with values above 127 will use multiple bytes which probably
>   won’t work with the device attached to the serial port. The only
>   encoding that converts all characters with a value 0-255 to a single
>   byte with the corresponding value and vice versa when converting bytes
>   to characters is the "Western European (ISO)" encoding. Use the
>   following code to use this Encoding with the SerialPort class:
>
> ```
> SerialPort mySerialPort = new SerialPort("COM1");
> mySerialPort.Encoding = Encoding.GetEncoding(28591);
> ```

Comment: Wow, glad a checked back.  Thank you for the thorough answer! I would give you two up votes if I could.